# Multiple parents views with angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a view, which is a child of 2 views. 
I want to have different urls to restore it. (ex: #/activities/contact/12, #/search/contact/12 etc)

I haven't find a way to do that without duplicate the state definition.

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/',
    controller: function() {

    },
    templateUrl: 'main.abstract.html'
  })
  .state('activities', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: 'activities',
    template: function() {
      return 'ACTIVITY TEMPLATE <br><br><a ui-sref="activities()">activity</a> <br/><a ui-sref="search()">search</a><br><br><a ui-sref="organization()">orga</a>';
    },
  })
  .state('search', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: 'search',
    template: function() {
      return 'SEARCH TEMPLATE <br><br><a ui-sref="activities()">activity</a> <br/><a ui-sref="search()">search</a><br><br><a ui-sref="organization()">orga</a>';

    },
  })
  .state('organization', {
      parent: 'main',
      url: '/contacts/:id',
      views: {
        "right@main": {
          template: function() {
            return 'orga loaded';
          }
        },
      }
  })
```

Plunkr available here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hDZ1FQASKt8zctjNCOuF?p=preview

When the user click on the "orga link", it should load the view in the red bo, but keeping the current parent view in the green one.

Comment: "...keeping the current parent view in the green one" I do not understand that statement. Can you explain more? Trying your plunker everything seems ok.